# Integral of pdf and cdf normal standard distribution

Tags: integration, statistics, normal-distribution, density-function

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(a+bx)\phi(x)dx=\Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right) $$

I have a problem with showing the above result, where $\phi(x)$ and $\Phi(x)$ respectively are the pdf and cdf of the standard normal distribution. I've tried to prove it by calculating the pdf $\phi(a+bx)$ first and combine it with the pdf $\phi(x)$ but the result is complicated and doesn't yield $\phi\left(\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right) $ . I really need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Is $\Phi(a+bx)$ pdf or cdf?

Comment: $\Phi (a+bx) $ is cdf of normal standard and $\phi(x) $ is pdf of normal standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $N(0,\,1)$ iids $U,\,V$ and defining $W:=U-bV\sim N(0,\,1+b^2)$, we can write the integral as $$\int_{\Bbb R}P(U\le a+bx)dP(V\le x)=P(U\le a+bV)=P(W\le a)=\Phi\bigg(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\bigg).$$

Comment: Hi, I have a small question. How did you get the first inequality ? I mean this one


$\int_{\Bbb R}P(U\le a+bx)dP(V\le x)=P(U\le a+bV)$

Comment: @SauhardSharma $dP(V\le x)$ is the pdf of $V$. The integral $V$-averages $P(U\le a+bx)$.

Comment: Is there any way to do it using normal integrals, because I have been trying without much luck for some time. I write the cdf in its integral form but after that no matter how many variables I change I can't proceed. The LHS becomes a double integral whereas the RHS contains only a single integral and I'm stuck after that

Comment: @What do you mean by normal integrals? These are integrals involving the normal distribution. Or did you mean "integrals where I don't think about the statistical meaning of it by these averaging arguments"? Because the whole point of Kildah Naraiq's problem is that it's begging to be solved by thinking in stats.

Comment: I'm afraid I meant the latter as I'm unfamiliar with the averaging arguments concepts. If you have any suggestions for good literature regarding the topic, I'd love to know

Comment: @SauhardSharma I don't have specific literature suggestions, but this particular problem uses the fact that a linear combination of independent Gaussians is Gaussian too. The usual way that's proven, using characteristic functions, could have been used to solve this problem too. You might want to work through it as an exercise, either until you get the solution or until you realise how "gnarly" it is, *or* until you get an intuition for how averaging works by thinking in terms of such Fourier transforms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85984/discussion-between-sauhard-sharma-and-j-g).